# Reshape Postgres table, long to wide

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering the following time series data in Postgres 9.5.1, I am trying to reshape to an
array(int) |time_to_failure(double) as new table

```
# SELECT acoustic_data, time_to_failure FROM lanl_train WHERE 
time_to_failure = '0.000795';
 acoustic_data | time_to_failure 
---------------+-----------------
             2 |        0.000795
             5 |        0.000795
             6 |        0.000795
             1 |        0.000795
             2 |        0.000795
             5 |        0.000795
             8 |        0.000795
             5 |        0.000795
             4 |        0.000795
             4 |        0.000795
             7 |        0.000795
             2 |        0.000795
             2 |        0.000795
             0 |        0.000795
             0 |        0.000795
             2 |        0.000795
             4 |        0.000795
             5 |        0.000795
             4 |        0.000795
(19 rows)

# SELECT ARRAY(SELECT acoustic_data FROM lanl_train WHERE 
time_to_failure = '0.000795');
                  array                  
-----------------------------------------
 {2,5,6,1,2,5,8,5,4,4,7,2,2,0,0,2,4,5,4}
(1 row)
```

So that a row in new table would be

```
acoustic_data(array) | time_to_failure(double)
----------------------------------------------
{2,5,6,1,2,5,8,5,4,4,7,2,2,0,0,2,4,5,4} | 0.000795
```

I have some of the parts but am stuck on SELECT to achieve this result. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `array_agg` ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)) with a group by:

```
select
    array_agg(lanl_train.acoustic_data) as acoustic_data,
    lanl_train.time_to_failure
from
    lanl_train
where
    lanl_train.time_to_failure = '0.000795'
group by
    lanl_train.time_to_failure
```

Comment: and where lanl_train.time_to_failure = lanl_train.time_to_failure, in the case that there are some 150k different time_to_failure(s)?

Comment: I guess, more importantly, is the order of acoustic_data maintained?

Comment: but lanl_train.time_to_failure = lanl_train.time_to_failure works for `SELECT 15041`.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I was busy last night and didn't see your comments. I'm not sure what your first or third ones mean, but array_agg does preserve the tuple order unless overridden within the aggregate function like `array_agg(table.column order by table.other_column asc)`

Comment: Worked great, array order preserved on `SELECT 15041` cases.